# How did this form know that I used autocomplete?

Tags: javascript, forms, autocomplete

I signed up for a free account at 96Down.com using Chrome, which auto-filled some of the fields for me (last name and email address).

When I submitted the form, those fields were highlighted asking me to make sure I fill out those fields. Were they somehow able to detect that I didn't manually fill in these fields?

I must admit I haven't had time to look at their code, I was just wondering if anyone already knows of this.

Comment: Note to VTCers: The OP is definitely not asking for an off-site resource. Moreover, how JS could be used to detect autocomplete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They could keep a boolean for each field and set it to true if the field got focus. That way they'd know if autocomplete was used (if any of those booleans are still false, autocomplete must have been used).

There may be other techniques - why don't you look at the source of 96Down.com and enlighten us?

Comment: Interesting... I wonder why anyone would implement something like this though.

Comment: Yup that's exactly what they did. Thank you @DaveHilditch

Answer (score 0):

96down.com uses the amember script, if you need more info on it just visit http://www.amember.com/

Aled